# problema con un query

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una especie de factura en el cual se realiza un calculo del usuario que se loguea de cuanto debe pagar en ese mes de factura (es de condominio) en el query donde se realiza el calculo le agrego que realice de insertar datos en una tabla para guardar el monto que se genero de ese usuario en el mes, pero tengo un inconveniente que cada vez que ese usuario entra al modulo o pagina donde se muestra la factura se agrega a la tabla dicho monto, es decir si entra 10 veces a la pagina se agrega 10 veces los datos a la tabla, lo que quiero hacer es que se agregue solo 1 sola vez mensual( ya que la factura es mensual) sin importar cuantas veces entre a la pagina, este es el codigo...refiriendome en la parte del insert into recibo

```js
 <?php
                        error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

  $ip_global = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Guyana');
  $global_fecha = date("d-m-y H:i:s");
 require_once('../conexion.php');

 $alicuota= $_SESSION['alicuota'];
   $sql = "SELECT SUM( monto ) as total
FROM gasto_g
WHERE YEAR( create_at ) = YEAR( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
AND MONTH( create_at ) = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
ORDER BY create_at ASC"; 
   $Resultado = mysqli_query ($conexion,$sql); 
    while ($Datos = mysqli_fetch_array($Resultado)){
      
      $alicuota= $_SESSION['alicuota'];
            $total1=($Datos['0'] * $alicuota)/100;

 $id= $_SESSION['id'];
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO recibo VALUES('','$total1','$id')";

$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
if ($query) {
  ?>
  
  <?php
}
    
?>
```

Comment: No guardas la fecha del recibo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer una búsqueda en la tabla `recibo` y si no encuentras ninguna fila para ese usuario, entonces recién ahí ejecutar el `insert`.

Algo así (estoy inventando los nombres de campos, no se si se llaman usuario_id y fecha):

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$mes = date('m');
$anio = date('Y');

$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM recibo 
          WHERE usuario_id = $id
          AND YEAR(fecha) = $anio
          AND MONTH(fecha) = $mes";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

// si no se encontró nada para ese usuario...
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    // ... calcular y ejecutar INSERT
}
```

Otra opción podría ser usar un cronjob en el servidor, que ejecute una vez por mes un script para calcular los montos de todos los usuarios. Luego cuando un usuario se loguea ya no necesitás hacer el cálculo en ese mismo momento.

En los servidores se pueden programar tareas, en el caso de Linux esto se hace con un comando `cronjob`. Básicamente consiste en indicar la ruta de un archivo a ejecutar y qué fecha y hora debe ejecutarse.
En tu caso, sería un archivo PHP que mensualmente genere todos los `inserts` en la tabla `recibo`.

Comment: tus 2 opciones me llaman la atencion, me pudieras orientar en como hacer lo que me comentas, mayormente en la busqueda de la tabla

Comment: ahí amplié mi respuesta!

Comment: Por eso preguntaba por si guardaba la fecha. Al ejecutar ese `select`, cuando haya guardado el mes anterior lo va a conseguir al usuario en esa tabla. ¿Como guarda el mes actual?

Comment: Arriba esta esa consulta amigo

Comment: Es cierto, olvidé ponerlo en la consulta. Quizás esté usando CURRENT_TIMESTAMP en el diseño de la tabla y por eso no se lo esté pasando por código.

Comment: si estoy usando el current_time...

Comment: ` $query2 = 'SELECT * FROM recibo WHERE id = ' . $_SESSION['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  $alicuota= $_SESSION['alicuota'];
            $total1=($Datos['0'] * $alicuota)/100;
             $id= $_SESSION['id'];
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO recibo VALUES('','$id','$total1')";
}
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
if ($query) {
  ?>
  
  <?php
}
    
?>` coloco eso y me dice expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result y sigue agregando los datos cada vez que ingresas a la pagina

Comment: Actualicé la consulta de búsqueda agregando que se compruebe que sea el mes actual.

Comment: En el código que pusiste ahí, te quedó `mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)` fuera de `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)`. Debería estar dentro.

Comment: $query2 = "SELECT * 
          FROM recibo 
          WHERE id = '$id'
          YEAR = YEAR( CURRENT_DATE( ) ) 
AND MONTH = MONTH( CURRENT_DATE( ) );
         ";

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   $alicuota= $_SESSION['alicuota'];
            $total1=($Datos['0'] * $alicuota)/100;

            $consulta = "INSERT INTO recibo VALUES('','$id','$total1')";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
}

if ($query) {
  ?>
  
  <?php
}
    
?>
 Sigue el mismo error y sigue agregando los datos

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión personal lo mejor es crear una llave primaria, para que tengas integridad en tu sistema, y posteriormente generas la validacion puedes utilizar un if exists para validar si existe el registro y luego insertarlo yo generaría un store procedure y mi validación dentro de este.

Comment: en la tabla recibo tiene su llave primaria que es idrecibo, y el idusuario es la fk de la tabla usuarios, que en esa tabla esa (idusuarios) es la pk

Comment: bien la llave primaria no quiere decir que es un identity solamente, si no que tu quieres asegurar la integridad en este caso puedes colocar id, año y mes, asegurando así que no se repita la información, ahora si no quieres cambiar la llave primaria, puedes generar una restricción de tipo unique. saludos